# Django doesn't load second page

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have just started Django, and I'm facing some difficulty.
When the first time I'm loading "localhost:8000/first_app" it is successfully loading index(), but on clicking on "About" link, url is changing to "localhost:8000/first_app/about/", but it is still loading "index()" and not "about()". Don't know what I'm missing.

Here's my project's URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
)
```

App's URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^about/', views.index, name='about'),
)
```

And views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says: Hello world! <br/> <a href='/first_app/about'>About</a>")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the ABOUT page! <br /> <a href='/first_app/'>Index</a>")
```

I'm using Django 1.7 and python 2.7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your URLs like this;

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Basically `'^$'` is the beginning & end of the match. The `^` is the start of the pattern & the `$` is the end of the pattern so keep that in mind when defining your URLs. It's good practice to use `$` to end your urls to avoid views being rendered regardless of what you add to the URL after what you match in your pattern.

Comment: @Amit that's because your `^about/` url actually points at your `index()` view.

Comment: Wrong. `'^$'` will match nothing. The order isn't important here. The only error is that both urls where pointed to the same view at `views.index`. The about regex will match too much. Like `about/this/is/stupid/`. The regex should end with `$` like so: `r'^about/$'`.